# I want to have a link to my facebook page from my blog

Tags: html, facebook, blogs

Every time I try to embed code that was recommended by another user, I get the same message: Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.
All I want is something on my page that a reader can click to take them to my Facebook page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post the code that gives you the error and the the text of the error itself

Comment: Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in.

Comment: and what's the code you are trying to embed?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a personal username for your account on facebook, check [Facebook Usernames general information](http://www.facebook.com/help/usernames/general), creating a username will provide you with a custom url something like

> www.facebook.com/YOURUSERNAMEHERE

you can easily add this to your blog by using the following html

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/YOURUSERNAMEHERE">Follow me on facebook</a>
```

Comment: I did that. I changed my Facebook URL to something easy and simple, and place that in the code where I was told to but I keep getting the message that the correct id for that specific page could not be retrieved and to verify that the correct href was passed in.   this makes no sense to me.

Comment: try logging into facebook wit your username and check whether it is correct one or not

Comment: This doesn’t open in the fb app

Answer (score 0):

It would also be helpful if you post the code that you're trying to use currently, otherwise no one has any idea what you're trying to do.

If you just want a link in HTML to your facebook page, put this into your page:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxx/xxxxxx">My Facebook Page</a>
```

The section that goes within the quotes should be the URL you see when you navigate to your Facebook page.

Comment: OK, with this I am sure that it is something that I am either adding or leaving out that is giving me the error message. but yeah- I want a button of some sort that readers can click that will direct them to my FB page.

Comment: Not working 2023

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a Page or Profile?
For Pages, the Like Box plugin is probably the best option, and lets people like the Page right from your website: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

For your own Profile, there's Badges ( https://www.facebook.com/badges/ ) which you can use

If it's your own Profile and you want people to Subscribe to you ('Follow') - there's a subscribe button you can use for this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/

Answer (score -3):

i dont know why, but for some reason, you have to include the http:// before the link